# Athena SQL query to check conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Hello I want to use athena SQL query to check the database name

example in mySQL php I can use database() == "xyz" If true then do something but in athena sql I am not able to do that.

```
SELECT "Year",
       "Covid Scenario",
       "M3 Scenario (Regulation-Tech-Consumer)",
       "Metric",
       "Mode",
       "Region",
       "Country and regions/areas",
       "Archetype",
       "City",
       SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM m3
WHERE "Covid Scenario" IN ('Virus contained')
  AND "M3 Scenario (Regulation-Tech-Consumer)" IN ('High-High-Medium')
  AND "Metric" IN ('Sales')
  AND "Mode" IN ('testing')
  <HERE I want to do something such as sleep if database name == "test">
```

Please tell me How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query `information_schema.tables` to get the database of the table name

```
SELECT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = 'm3';
```